# Row number change while save numpy ndarray in to text or read from .txt file

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy ndarray, shape is (R,1). I wonder if I firstly store it into a .txt file, and then load out. But in this process, total line number decrease for 1. 
Codes I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np  
from numpy import loadtxt

dictkey=dict.keys()
Xarr=np.array(dictkey).reshape(-1,1)
print Xarr.shape

np.savetxt('filepath/file.txt', Xarr, fmt='%s')

f = open("step_2/Part_DBS/S3_DBs/GO_For_SVM.txt")
f.readline()  # skip the header
X = np.loadtxt(f)
print X.shape
```

In print Xarr.shape, row number is 15431, and in print X.shape, row number becomes to 15430. How it comes? And I wonder if the row order will change, I hope it totally unchanged.
Ps:
if I just use
    `np.savetxt('filepath/file.txt', Xarr)`
There will be error
    `TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S28218') and format specifier ('%.18e')`
My python version is Python 2.7.13

Comment: Why do you think that you need `readline`? Don't you think `loadtxt` can readily read the output of `savetxt`?

Comment: What header are you trying to skip? You didn't write one with `savetxt`.  Did you look at the text file?

Comment: As for your PS, that means that `Xarr` has string dtype, and can't be written as a float (the default format).  That `S28218` dtypes looks suspicious.  Your array contains a lot of very long strings.  Is that intentional?